# Counting number of X character

Tags: php, string

I'm experimenting with something where explode() is failing so I want to try something else. If I have a string, how can I count the number of characters in it that are let's say a `comma` as in `,`

Comment: You want **str_word_count** http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
substr_count($text, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`count_chars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

Example from PHP Manual:

```
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";
foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
```

Output ([codepad](http://codepad.org/FnpZseKj)):

```
There were 4 instance(s) of " " in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "." in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "F" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "T" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "a" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "d" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "e" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "n" in the string.
There were 2 instance(s) of "o" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "s" in the string.
There were 1 instance(s) of "w" in the string.
```

Comment: Don't forget to check  `isset($result[','])` if there's no guarantee a comma is in the string (possibility for no comma element in the result array)