# Get The Number of Sepecific String Inside String

Tags: php

if I have a string something like this:

> ```
> $string = '01122028K,02122028M,03122028K,04122028M,05122028K,06122028P-2,07122028K,08122028P-';
> ```

How can I do to get the number of 'K' inside string **$string.** In this case K would be 4.
I know it can be solved by the help strpos() through out the looping after explode the $string into array. Is any php function to do it in straightforward  way?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the `substr_count()` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting number of X character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455013/counting-number-of-x-character)

Comment: substr_count() only works for '021222K', '0212332K'. But it can't distinguish the existing K and K-1'. So, if I have '0232323K', '0329322K-1' it still return 2. I dont want this. It should 1

Comment: Where did you say that in your question? What characters are allowed after `K`, what characters are not allowed?

Comment: You can subtract the count of `K-` if that's the only thing you want to filter out. Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: I just want this:
if 0123333K, 323232K => K = 2;
if 0132323K, 232323K-1 => K = 1; K-1 = 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "There are " . substr_count($string, 'K') . " K's in the string";
```

If you don't want to count `K-1` this can be:

```
echo "There are " . substr_count($string, 'K')-substr_count($string, 'K-') . " K's in the string";
```

To solve the new problem in the comments:

```
$string = '01122028K,02122028M,02122028K-1,02122028K-2,03122028K,04122028M,05122028K-1,04122028M,05122028K,06122028P-2,07122028K,08122028P-';
preg_match_all('/K(?:-\d+)?/', $string, $match);
$counts = array_count_values($match[0]);
print_r($counts);

Array
(
    [K] => 4
    [K-1] => 2
    [K-2] => 1
)
```

Comment: You should have said so in the first place, instead of wasting people's time with a question much simpler than what you really wanted.

Comment: A simpler pattern with the same effect: `~K[^,]*~`  A shame this question didn't have a better [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try also this solution:

```
$string = '01122028K,02122028M,03122028K,04122028M,05122028K,06122028P-2,07122028K,08122028P-';
$strlen = strlen($string);
$count = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {
    $char = substr( $string, $i, 1 );
    // $char contains the current character, so do your processing here
    if ($char == "K")
        $count++:
}
```

then...

```
echo $count;
```

That's not a "straightforward way" BUT I found it useful since it's very flexible and you can manipulate all sort of code on your string.

Good Luck!