# Counting the number of specific characters inside string

Tags: php, string

I'm sorry, I just found a new problem due to my question about:
[Get The Number of Sepecific String Inside String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160282/get-the-number-of-sepecific-string-inside-string/16160305?noredirect=1#comment23094348_16160305).

I have been trying hard, how to find the number of specific character inside a string? The case something like this.

```
function get_num_chars($char) {
    $string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1'
}
```

If I pass `get_num_chars(M) would return 2` 
If I pass `get_num_chars(M-1) would return 1`

I tried `count_chars()`, `substr_count()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that when something contains `K-1` it also contains `K`. How is the function supposed to know not to count these? You need to define the problem more carefully.

Comment: @Barmar: OP didn't specify that `K-1` shouldn't match?

Comment: @Aquillo he did specify... He wants if (M) to return 2 and if (M-1) to return 1.... "Barmar" is right.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. In that case you'd be best of to count the matches of regex, like `count matches of char not followed by dash` or `count matches of char followed by comma or end of line`

Comment: I just though the solutions is using regex to distinguish the occurrence 'K' (K isn't followed with '-1') and K-1 (K is followed by -1). How to write it in Regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution using regular expression:

```
function get_num_chars($char) {
    $string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1';
    return preg_match_all('/'.$char.'(?=,|$)/', $string, $m);
}

echo get_num_chars('M');    // 2
echo get_num_chars('M-1');  // 1
echo get_num_chars('M-2');  // 1
echo get_num_chars('K');    // 1
echo get_num_chars('K-1');  // 1
```

Comment: Look up "lookaround" on regular-expression.info

Comment: This will fail if the size of the string is very high.

Comment: @Munt please describe "very high".

Comment: @mickmackusa very large string, perhaps? I forgot what I meant there since I no longer use PHP.

Comment: There is no benefit in declaring `$m` if you are merely going to return the match count.

Answer (score 17):

It is possible with [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

I think you are not passing a value to it properly. Try it like this:

```
$string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1';

echo substr_count($string, 'K-1'); //echo's 1

echo substr_count($string, 'K'); // echo's 2
```

Comment: He wants the second one to echo `1`, not `2`.

Comment: Yes. Barmar is right.

When searching 'K', 'K-1' is excluded. So, substr_count($string, 'K') should 1

Comment: possible solution: `$string = str_replace('K-1', '', $string)` after `K-1` was count.

Comment: As stated by others, this answer will yield incorrect results in scenarios where a needle string exists inside a larger substring.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It might not be feasible, but it addresses your problem.

```
function get_num_chars($char) {

    $string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1';
    echo substr_count($string, $char);
}

get_num_chars('M,');
get_num_chars('M-1');
get_num_chars('k,');
```

Comment: So what if the last charset end with `K`? There's no comma at the end.

Comment: As said earlier, the string when searched for K will also match K-1. So the coder will need to check thoroughly on his inputs.

Comment: Yes, but say `$string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1, 2323K';`. The last entry won't be matched by `'K,'`

Comment: Its easy to solve. Add a padding `$string .= ','` and remove it afterwards with `rtrim` (if `$string` is needed elsewhere).

Comment: As stated elsewhere on this page, this answer will yield incorrect results in scenarios where a needle string exists inside a larger substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
$k_count = substr_count($string, 'K') - substr_count($string, 'K-');
$k1_count = substr_count($string, 'K-1');
```

or

`Counting K not followed by dash` as follows:

```
$k_count = preg_match_all('/*K(?!-)/*', $string, $out);
```

Comment: Me thinks you didn't test your regex.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $string = '120201M, 121212M-1, 21121212M, 232323M-2, 32323K, 323232K-1';

 $wordCounts = array_count_values(str_word_count($string,1));

 echo $mCount = (isset($wordCounts['M-'])) ? $wordCounts['M'] : 0;
```

But here is one thing. You can just pass the 'M-' or 'M', not 'M-1'. It is some workaround for what you want. Because str_word_count matches the exact word count being used.

Comment: `str_word_count()` mutilates the data -- ergo `M-1` is unsearchable. Proof: https://3v4l.org/i6VvF