# how to write a php code

Tags: php, mysql

As i am new to the php . I need some help from the friends. So i am posting the questions

I have retrieved the data from database and the data is extracted like this.

```
Country Cricketers   ball
INDIA    DHONI        45        
         Raina
         ASHWIN
 NZ      VETTORI      20
         BOND
AUS      WATSON       10
         WARNE
BAN      HASAN        100
```

But i have to divide the ball column equally in the particular team like it must show me as below

```
Country  Cricketers  ball

INDIA     Dhoni       15   //Above table 45 has divided for 3 players so 15 each 
          Raina       15
          Ashwin      15
NZ        VETTORI     10   //Above table 20 has divided for 2 players so 10 each
          BOND        10
AUS       WATSON      5    //Above table 10 has divided for 2 players so 5 each
          WARNE       5
BAN       HASAN       100 //Above players has only one player so 100 remains same
```

And my code is like this

```
$name = $row["country_name"];
$replace_players = preg_replace('/,/', '<br/>', $cricket_names);       
$ball = $row["ball"]; // i am extracting from database
```

```
<tbody>
   <td>'.$name."<br>".'</td> 
   <td>'.$replace_players."<br>".'</td>
   <td>'.$ball."<br>".'</td>           // i have to change it here such that it will distribute dynamically                                           
   <td>'.____________________.'</td>
</tr>';
```

please help me in solving this issue

Comment: Did you write this PHP yourself?

Comment: `please help me in solving this issue` http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-bP6k59dMHBI/UnQmzKaljjI/AAAAAAAAZUA/3ZDsMcXw4d0/s400/grumpy-cat-8141_preview_zps9177ab07.png - look at the syntax highlighting. Its obvious where the error is, come on. Dont let us do your work.

Comment: Count the number of comma's in $cricket_names. Add 1, then divide $ball by that number. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16162719/1685196)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write the php code to print the below example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328266/how-to-write-the-php-code-to-print-the-below-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thing you want this

```
 $name = $row["country_name"];
 $cricket_names = $row["cricket_names"]; 
 $ball = $row["ball"];

$arr_players = explode(",", $cricket_names);  
$player_count = sizeof($arr_players);
$each_ball = floor($ball/$player_count);  

for($i=0; i<$player_count; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$arr_players[$i].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$each_ball.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```